# std streams to write to void* and back

Tags: c++

How can I get fstream to write to a void pointer?

Basically I've used MapFileView and got a void pointer from it for shared memory.

I've use copymemory to copy a bunch of data back and forth between two separate applications.

Now instead, I want to use the std library to read in a struct via << overload and write it to my mapped memory (Local\MyMemMap, invalid_handle), then read it back via >> overload. It's not a physical file that you can see.

Basically I want to redirect ifstream and ofstream to my void* if possible. Otherwise, what other std streams would allow me to use my pointer and the operator overloads?

I only know of istream, osstream.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to write a custom stream to read and write from your mapped memory. This [web page](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf) may help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That way, if the link ever goes down (and this happens more often than you might think), your answer will still be helpful to others.

Comment: And the link is dead as Cody warned.

Answer (score 3):

operator<< and operator>> are meant for formatted input and output. Sounds like you are reading and writing raw bytes. You should use istream::read and ostream::write for that.

Comment: OK I think I've misunderstood your question. You want to write a custom stream that reads and writes to your mapped file. That's a very different thing.

Comment: I used stringstream with rdbuf and pbufset and it seems to work pretty well. Yeah I'm reading/writing raw bytes from a struct. I just didn't like calling CopyMemory every single time.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason for which `std::strstream` is deprecated since C++98 but has not be removed from the C++11 standard. There is a better alternative for most of its use (`std::stringstream`) but no standard replacement for the possibility to use a fixed buffer. You don't have to write your own `std::streambuf`, just use

```
#include <strstream>

std::strstream memostream(reinterpret_cast<char*>(mem), memsize, reinterpret_cast<char*>(mem));
```

to have a stream writing to your memory positioned for writing at start. And

```
std::strstream memistream(reinterpret_cast<char*>(mem), memsize);
```

for a stream reading at start of it.

Comment: Note also that `std::istrstream` can take a `char const*` input, for a read-only stream.

Comment: This seems to solve my immediate problem, and there's no indication yet that it's going to be removed. But I'm still torn about using a deprecated feature.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't think it will be removed without a replacement for all use cases, after all this lack is why it hasn't been yet, and if my reading of the committee is right there is a push for a more in depth reworking of the IO and formatting facilities. The first step in that direction was [`<format>`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/format). Depending on your requirements, you may want to look at `std::format_to` and if C++20 is an issue for you, there is [`{fmt}`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) on which the standard feature was based.